# Instantiate the next item when the first item is dropped

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a script that instantiate gameobjects when the player buys X amount from the shop, it works but I came across a problem. You see, say if the player buy about 200 items, my game will lag; I made a script that setactive the every item above one to false however it still makes my game lag.

Which is not desirable, I was wondering if there is a way to keep the number (int) of items the player buys but instantiate the item when the player drops (setting a child out of it's parent) the first item into a specific area.

So say if the player buys 3 items, one is already instantiated but the next two isn't, then when the player drops the first item into a specific area the next one is instantiated but the third one isn't yet instantiated until the second one is also placed in the specific area. This is my instantiating script:

```
void Update () {

        if (happenOnce == false) {
            for (int x = 0; x < slotCon.GetComponent<SlotController> ().Wallet; x++) {
                var item = Instantiate (ItemPrefab) as GameObject;
                item.transform.position = transform.position;
                item.transform.SetParent (slotHolder.transform);
                item.SetActive (true);
            }
            happenOnce = true;
         }
}
```

Comment: Personally, I would split the large block of words into smaller, more readable paragraphs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this would work for your specific predicament (and i'm not exactly sure of the specifics of your shop).

I would keep a record of the amount of items that have been instantiate in the loop and the amount of items that have been dropped.Then, if i follow your logic, you only want the next item to spawn if the previous one has been dropped so we could do.

```
if (droppeditemscount >= instantiateditemscount)
{
instantiate()
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggest, sorry I took so long for me to reply; I had work. I am now back on my project and tried what you suggested but adapted the function to meet my needs. The idea you gave me was a huge help, I was able to instantiate prefabs into my game once the first prefab was dropped into an area, however I am still having issues as my game is still lagging. I thought by instantiating 1 item into the inventory after the player has dropped a previous item down into the game would help make my game smooth.

Comment: But when I buy X (say 100) amount of items (only 1 being instantiated again and again once the default/first item is dropped by the player), my game is still lagging and sometimes crash.

Comment: what kind of collider are you using on the instantiated object ? if it has too many polygons it could make the game lag.

Comment: I have two box colliders 2d one on the instantiated object and the other is on the item's child.

Comment: Unfortunately i don't think i can help you without having access to the project since lag can be caused by a multitude of things. you may want to look into basic optimisation, occlusion culling and other techniques.